# Checking whether the usage of Fubini's theorem is possible

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let's define
$$\Gamma(z) = \int \limits_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} \, t^{z-1} \, dt, \qquad z \in \mathbb{C}, \quad \text{Re}(z) > 0.$$
It's just a standard Gamma function.

Now let's consider closed curve $C \in \mathbb{C}$ smooth in pieces.

I wonder if it is possible to use Fubini's theorem in the following integral
$$\oint \limits_{C} \int \limits_{1}^{\infty} e^{-t} \, t^{z-1} \, dt \, dz.$$
If yes, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: to apply Fubini's Theorem it is enough to check integrability on the product space. Here $|t^{z-1}|=t^{\Re z -1}$. If $C$ is a closed path contained in $\{z: Re z >0\}$ the there exists $r>0$ such that $\Re z >r$ for all $z$ on $C$. Can now check integrability?

Suppose $C$ is given by $\gamma:[0,1] \to \mathbb C$. Then $\int_0^{1}\int_1^{\infty} |e^{-t}t^{z-1}||\gamma '(s)|dtds=\int_0^{1}\int_1^{\infty} |e^{-t}t^{x-1}||\gamma '(s)|dtds$ where $x=\Re z$. Hence $\int_0^{1}\int_1^{\infty} |e^{-t}t^{z-1}||\gamma '(s)|dtds\leq \int_0^{1}\int_1^{\infty} |e^{-t}t^{r-1}||\gamma '(s)|dtds$ where $r$ is as described above. Since $\gamma$ is assumed to be piecewise smooth it follows that $|\gamma'(s)|$ is bounded. If $M$ is a bound for this then we get $\int_0^{1}\int_1^{\infty} |e^{-t}t^{z-1}||\gamma '(s)|dtds \leq M\Gamma (r) <\infty$.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more this equality: $|t^{z-1}|=t^{\Re z -1}$?

Comment: $|e^{(z-1)log t|}=e^{(x-1)log t}$ where $x$ is the real part of $z$.

Comment: Thank you. However I still don't know how to check the integrability. One more tip?

Comment: @Hendrra I have added a detailed proof.

Comment: Thank you very much! Of course by $Re$ and $\Re$ you mean real part of $z$, don't you?

Comment: Yes, I wrote $\Re z$ for the real part of $z$.

Comment: The last question -- what is $r$? And how do we know that there exists a number such that $\Re z > t$? $t$ might be really big number

Comment: $\gamma [0,1]$, being continuous image of a compact set, is compact. For any compact set $K$ contained in $Re(z)>0$  there exist $r>0$ such that $Re(z) \geq r$ for all $z \in K$.

Comment: Now everything is clear. Thank you for your time and great explanation!